# sql foward reference syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, syntax

Im new to SQL so I dont know the terminology and am am making words up, but I dont know where to look for this syntax -

`select name = p.e_full_Name 
from db..port p, db..port_x il 
where p.port_id = il.port_id and p.port_id = "blah"`

From what I can deduce, `name` is going to be the name of the p.e_full_name column, `p` and `il` are variables defined in the from statement (`p` is `db..port` table, `il` is `db.port_x` table). Is this correct? What is this syntax called, and where can I read up on it?

Comment: This is actually called a JOIN, but using very old syntax...

Comment: what  is `..` means ?

Comment: the db..port is syntax (typically from SQL-Sever) indicating database name (db).<owner>.table.   In the case of .., the owner name is skipped

Answer (score 1):

This is the old syntax of JOIN operation between two tables.

p and il are alias for respective tables.

The recommended syntax for query like yours  is

Select col
From table1 t1
Join table t2
On t1.column=t2.column

Use indexing on columns on which joining is done to improve performance

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT columns
FROM <table> <alias>
JOIN <anotherTable> <differentAlias>
ON alias.column = differentAlias.column
WHERE alias.column = 'Blah'
```

In your example, p and il as aliases for the tables, to save typing the table name again.  The p.port_id = il.port_id is a joining condition (should be part of the ON clause)

```
select name = p.e_full_Name 
from db..port p, db..port_x il 
where p.port_id = il.port_id and p.port_id = "blah"
```

Search for JOIN, you'll find examples.   Adapt the code to the first example, your example is an old style JOIN that shouldn't be used anymore

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** Is this correct?

**A:** Basically, yes.

But in regards to the reference to **`name`** in

```
 SELECT name = expr ...
```

that's an **alias** assigned to the expression. And the resultset returned from the query will include that assigned **alias** as the column name.

That syntax is a non-standard extension in SQL Server (not supported in Oracle or MySQL). It's equivalent to the ANSI standard:

```
SELECT expr AS name ...
```

In regards to **`p`** and **`il`** in the query, those aren't really variables. Each of those is also an**alias** assigned to a table, rather than to expression in the SELECT list. A reference to a table **alias** elsewhere in the query are references to the table. For just a simple table, an alias is not required. In the more general case, we are required to assign an alias to some row sources (a table that is referenced more than one time in a query, and inline views). So, assigning an alias is a familiar, so familiar, it's pattern we follow for simple tables as well.

**Q:** What is this syntax called, and where can I read up on it?

Both table and column **alias** are part of the ANSI SQL standard.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28SQL%29)